# Error: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'n_splits'

Tags: python-2.7, scikit-learn, shuffle, cross-validation

I am going to perform `ShuffleSplit()` method for California housing dataset (Source: https://www.dcc.fc.up.pt/~ltorgo/Regression/cal_housing.html) to fit SGD regression.
However, the 'n_splits' error is occurred when method is applied.
The code is following:

```
from sklearn import cross_validation, grid_search, linear_model, metrics  
import numpy as np  
import pandas as pd


from sklearn.preprocessing import scale
from sklearn.cross_validation import ShuffleSplit


housing_data = pd.read_csv('cal_housing.csv', header = 0, sep = ',')
housing_data.fillna(housing_data.mean(), inplace=True)
df=pd.get_dummies(housing_data)


y_target = housing_data['median_house_value'].values
x_features = housing_data.drop(['median_house_value'], axis = 1)

from sklearn.cross_validation import train_test_split
from sklearn import model_selection

train_x, test_x, train_y, test_y = model_selection.train_test_split(x_features, y_target, test_size=0.2, random_state=4)
reg = linear_model.SGDRegressor(random_state=0)
cv = ShuffleSplit(n_splits = 10, test_size = 0.2, random_state = 0)
```

The error is below:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-22-8f8760b04f8c> in <module>()
----> 1 cv = ShuffleSplit(n_splits = 10, test_size = 0.2, random_state = 0)

TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'n_splits'
```

I updated scikit-learn with **0.18 version**.

Anaconda version:  **4.5.8**

Could you please advise on this issue?

Comment: Well, does `ShuffleSplit` accept an `n_splits` parameter?

Comment: Use `n=10` instead of `n_splits`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are mixing up two different modules.

Before 0.18, cross_validation was used for ShuffleSplit. In that, `n_splits` was not present. `n` was used to define the number of splits

But since you have updated to 0.18 now, `cross_validation` and `grid_search` has been deprecated in favor of model_selection.

This is mentioned in [docs here](http://scikit-learn.org/0.18/modules/classes.html#recently-deprecated), and these modules will be removed from version 0.20

So instead of this:

```
from sklearn.cross_validation import ShuffleSplit
from sklearn.cross_validation import train_test_split
```

Do this:

```
from sklearn.model_selection import ShuffleSplit
fro
```

m sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

Then you can use `n_splits`.

```
cv = ShuffleSplit(n_splits = 10, test_size = 0.2, random_state = 0)
```

Comment: @ArtyomMakarov If this answer helped, consider accepting it.