# TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'n_folds',sentiment_analysis_with_SVM

Tags: python-3.x, scikit-learn, svm, sentiment-analysis, sklearn-pandas

I am trying to implement svm for sentiment analysis, i trying to implement this gitlink https://github.com/jatinwarade/Sentiment-analysis-using-SVM/blob/master/SVM.ipynb.

```
from sklearn.model_selection import ShuffleSplit
from sklearn.model_selection import StratifiedKFold
```

i refered this as it says to change cross origin to model_selection since it is depricated [Error: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'n_splits'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51574788/error-init-got-an-unexpected-keyword-argument-n-splits)
so I replaced with this

```
grid_svm = GridSearchCV(
    pipeline_svm, #object used to fit the data
    param_grid=param_svm, 
    refit=True,  # fit using all data, on the best detected classifier
    n_jobs=-1,  # number of cores to use for parallelization; -1 for "all cores" i.e. to run on all CPUs
    scoring='accuracy',#optimizing parameter
    cv=StratifiedKFold(liked_train,n_folds=5),
)
```

This Returns Error:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-49-61dd1e818fa4> in <module>
      5     n_jobs=-1,  # number of cores to use for parallelization; -1 for "all cores" i.e. to run on all CPUs
      6     scoring='accuracy',#optimizing parameter
----> 7     cv=StratifiedKFold(liked_train,n_folds=5),
      8 )

TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'n_folds'
```

Please Help me solve this error

Comment: I tried adding n_split also, it return's the same error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you can see in the documentation for [`model_selected.StrafiedKFold`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.StratifiedKFold.html), there is no keyword argument called `n_folds` and you should indeed use `n_splits`.

Note, however, that the data should *not* be passed as an argument to the validator and by doing so, you're effectively passing `liked_train` as the argument for `n_splits`, which won't work. Rather, you should pass the data only to the `fit` of your `grid_svm` after initialization.

Comment: I tried adding n_split also, it return's the same error  :  TypeError: __init__() got multiple values for argument 'n_splits'

Comment: That's because the first argument to `StrafiedKFold` is `n_splits` and you're already passing `liked_train`. Change your call to be `cv=StratifiedKFold(n_splits=5)` and you're good.